# Two different jQuery in one html page

Tags: jquery, html

Two different jQuery on the same page and the page to be included has the newest jQuery

Comment: sorry...what? I don't see any question.

Comment: you must ask a question. This is A&Q site. You ask then we answer

Answer (score 4):

By reading what you have provided,

You can achieve this by running your version of jQuery in no-conflict mode. "No conflict" mode is the typical solution to get jQuery working on a page with other frameworks like prototype, and can be also be used here as it essentially namespaces each version of jQuery which you load.

```
<!-- load jQuery 1.8 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.8.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_8 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- load jQuery 1.9 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.9.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_9 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Comment: Since you are new here, accept the answer(tick) which solved your problem. Up-vote(up arrow) the answer(s) which give(s) you information or help(s) you. Down-vote(down arrow) the answer(s) which are fake.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is: "**How to use two versions of jQuery on one page?**"

The answer is: You can use **[jQuery.noConflict(true)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)**.